# How to use Environment Variables in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to use environment variables to pass my repo credentials when using built.sbt.

I have tried things like this but the details arent picked up.

```
credentials += Credentials("Some Nexus Repository Manager", "my.artifact.repo.net", System.getenv("USERNAME"), System.getenv("PASSWORD"))
```

I have also tried a credentials file under ~/.sbt/ but I'm not sure how to add environment variables to that.

If I just type my username and password normally in the credentials file it works so I know that the log in details are ok.

Additional:
I source the environment vars in a shell before running sbt compile.

Running

```
credentials += Credentials("Realm", "my.artifact.repo.net", sys.env("USERNAME"), sys.env("PASSWORD"))
```

results in a forbidden url error.

I should say I'm stuck trying to resolve dependencies

UPDATE:
The Following returns the correct value

```
eval scala.sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME")
```

But when I add this into my script

```
val username = scala.sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME")
val password = scala.sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD")
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "artifactory.link.io", username, password)

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Artifactory Snapshot" at "https://artifactory.link.io/art/libs-snapshot"
)
```

or

```
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "my.artifact.repo.net", sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME"), sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD"))
```

I get a FORBIDDEN URL error which suggests that the scala part runs ok but for some reason the credentials are still incorrect. If I explicitly set the credentials in the build.sbt it works.

Comment: Are you using actual environment variables or JVM properties? Are the environment variables exported from the shell? How does "not getting picked up" express itself, are the values null?

Comment: Added some stuff to answer this. I guess the values are null based on the error message

Comment: you can verify this. from your script run `sbt shell` and then type `eval sys.env("USERNAME")` and it should show the value if it exists.

Comment: I can return the username and password using this method. But using credentials += Credentials("Realm", "my.artifact.repo.net", sys.env("USERNAME"), sys.env("PASSWORD")) leads to a [error] Unable to find credentials for ["Realm" @ "my.artifact.repo.net",] error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get env variables with the commands mentioned other responses like:

```
sys.env.get("USERNAME")
sys.env.get("PASSWORD")
```

but they return an option of type Option[String]

To turn this into string you need to either do a match or simply use

```
sys.env.get("USERNAME").get
sys.env.get("USERNAME").getOrElse("some default value")
```

if you need to set some default value. Warning! calling .get of an option that does not have value will give you a runtime error.

Comment: how about instead using `sys.env.getOrElse("USERNAME", "some default value")` ?

Comment: As of August 2021, using sys.env.getOrElse() is the best approach to this especially if you are using IntelliJ, getOrElse() will not be valid.

    val someValue = sys.env.getOrElse("SOME_VALUE", "default some value")

Answer (score 9):

You can use anything that works in Scala in sbt, for instance:

```
sys.env.get("PASSWORD")
```

Comment: found   : Option[String]
     required: String    . I don't have much experience with scala, how can I cast this to just a string?

Comment: In sbt 1.2.1 my IntelliJ suggests using `sys.env("PASSWORD")` instead

Answer (score 4):

Adding your code to the example, sending Credentials strings for user id and password:

```
(sys.env.get("USERNAME"), sys.env.get("PASSWORD")) match {
  case (Some(username), Some(password)) => 
    println(s"Do my thing $username/$password")
    credentials += Credentials("Realm", "my.artifact.repo.net", username, password)
  case _ => 
    println("USERNAME and/or PASSWORD is missing")
    credentials ++= Seq()
}
```

Comment: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: sbt.internals.DslEntry
  case None => println("No password set")

Comment: @Glef - I'd need to see your code to see why you're having this error.

Comment: But in short - I'd expect that your code would be in the first case of the match, and use the strings in *username* and *password*.

Comment: See the latest edit. That should address your environment issue. Whether your credentials are set correctly is another question.

Comment: I just get the same type mismatches for your examples. I just copied your code exactly into the middle of my build.sbt and changed the env variables to match

Comment: I'd have to see your code to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the environment variables via `sys.env("VARIABLE")` or `System.getenv("VARIABLE")` will both work in build.sbt if they are correctly exported.

You may need to setup your credentials correctly ([general instructions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials)).

For Artifactory, it should look like this:

```
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/<repo-key>")
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "<host>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASS>")
```

Note that "Artifactory Realm" here is not an arbitrary string and must actually be exactly as stated.

Full instructions: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SBT+Repositories

Comment: credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "my.artifactory.io", sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME"), sys.env("ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD"))  returns  CLIENT ERROR: Forbidden url  . using sbt shell I can see the env variables do return the correct values

Comment: do I need to the publishto line if I am only trying to resolve some dependencies

Comment: To resolve dependencies, add a resolver: `resolvers += "my artifactory" at "http://my.artifactory.io"` or with a repositories file: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SBT+Repositories#SBTRepositories-Configuringsbt

Comment: I have that line, but the repo is password protected so sbt can't use it

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
val config :Config = ConfigFactory.load()
val username=config.getString(“USERNAME”)
val password = config.getString(“PASSWORD”)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(sys.env.get("USERNAME"), sys.env.get("PASSWORD")) match ...` didn't work with sbt 1.1.1.

Alternative solution from JFrog, here is a working example on github

https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/circleci-example/circleci-sbt-artifactory

Create a `credentials.properties` file at the root of your project instead of `~/.sbt/credentials`. Add it to `.gitignore`.

```
cat <<EOF > credentials.properties
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=gcartifactory-us.jfrog.info
user=$ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
password=$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD
EOF
```

Generate the file during before build time and make a reference to it in your 
`build.sbt`

```
credentials += Credentials(new File("credentials.properties"))
```

Comment: `sys.env.get("...")` works fine in sbt 1.2 and sbt 1.3 so you dont need any workarounds